# Evalaute $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan \left(\frac{1}{1+3k+k^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Evalaute : $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan \left( \frac{1}{1+3k+k^2} \right)$$

This problem is supposed to be solved using the formula: $$\arctan(a)-\arctan(b)=\arctan \left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab} \right)$$
How ever i can't two such $a$ and $b$ that solve the problem .

I've experimented with $a=k+3$ and $b=k$ but it yields : $\frac{3}{1+3k+k^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{1+3k+k^2}$

there's also $a=k+2$ and $b=k+1$ which give : $\frac{1}{k^2+3k+2}$ which doesn't solve the problem neither .

I've had many failed attempts and searched all over the net but couldn't find any thread on this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that a closed form expression exists for this sum ?

Comment: I am not actually ,  I only found this exercise online after trying for so many hours now , i  couldn't tell if i was just unabe to solve it or if it dind't have a closed form so that's why i made this thread

Comment: Mathematica says the sum is equivalent to the definite integral,$$\frac{\pi}2\int_0^1\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac\pi2\sqrt{5-4ix}\right)}{\sqrt{5-4ix}}+\frac{\tan\left(\frac\pi2\sqrt{5+4ix}\right)}{\sqrt{5+4ix}}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: It appears interesting that  $$\arctan\frac i2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac i{k^2+3k+1}\right)$$ so that the $\operatorname{arctanh}$ series returns $\operatorname{arctanh}\frac 12$.

Comment: How did you find/discover this formulas?  Should LHS be arctanh(i/2)?  Thanks.

Comment: Using $(3.16)$ from [Kunle Adegoke's paper about sums of arctangents](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10156.pdf). If you replace your $\arctan$ by $\operatorname{arctanh}$ you'll get $\operatorname{arctanh}\frac 12$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using complex form we have
$$ \tan^{-1}x=\Im (\ln(1+xi)) $$
then
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k^2+3k+1} \right)=\Im\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{i}{k^2+3k+1} \right)\right) $$
So
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k^2+3k+1} \right)=\Im \left(\ln \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{i}{k^2+3k+1} \right) \right) $$
to calculate the product we have
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{i}{k^2+3k+1} \right)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(k+\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-i} \right)\left(k+\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-i}  \right)}{\left(k+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)\left(k+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}  \right)}$$
using the formula
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{p=1}^{n} \frac{k+a_p}{k+b_p}=\prod_{p=1}^{n} \frac{\Gamma(b_p+1)}{\Gamma(a_p+1)}  , \text{    where     } \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-b_k)=0 , a_k\ne b_m \text{ for any }k,m\in N $$
So
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{i}{k^2+3k+1} \right)= \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}  \right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-i} \right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-i}  \right)} $$
we can show easily that
$$ \Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}  \right)=-\pi \sec \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} \pi}{2} \right)$$
and
$$ \Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-i} \right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}-i}  \right)=-2\pi \sec \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{5-4i} \right) $$
So
$$ \Im \left(\ln \frac{-\pi \sec \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} \pi}{2} \right)}{-2\pi \sec \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{5-4i} \right)} \right)=\arg\left(-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{5-4i} \right) \right)$$
by long computing we can get
$$ \arg\left(-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{5-4i} \right) \right)=\tan^{-1} \left(\text{tanh}\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{-5+\sqrt{41}}}{2\sqrt{2}} \right)\tan\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{5+\sqrt{41}}}{2\sqrt{2}} \right) \right) $$
finally
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k^2+3k+1} \right)=\tan^{-1} \left(\text{tanh}\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{-5+\sqrt{41}}}{2\sqrt{2}} \right)\tan\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{5+\sqrt{41}}}{2\sqrt{2}} \right) \right)$$

Comment: Wow , i did not expect that a problem for highscoolers would have a solution as elegant and complex . I think now that the problem poser just made a typo but it resulted in quite an interesting discovery . Beautiful answer !